# Multi-Bundles in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I create project from Symfony 2, but I have a problem:
In project have multi-bundles(ex: AdminBundle and FontEndBundle)

1. Case 1: Doctrine orm and Entities generate on FrontEndBundle, then from AdminBundle, I will call Entity via `FrontEndBundle:Object` it work OK.
2. Case 2: I want to config structure folow

   src/Project/

   - Model/Entity
   - OrmYml/doctrine/orm
   - Bundles(contains FontEndBundle & AdminBundle)
   - Extensions

In case 2, How do I config Entity mapping to generate Entities to `src/Model/Entity` directory ? Because when I using Command: `doctrine:generate:entities Project/Model/Entity`,

> error :  Namespace "Project\Model\Entity" does not contain any mapped
>   entities.

Answer (score 0):

How do you declare your entities ?You should put your entities within a bundle. You cant have them outside a bundle .

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Symfony developpers create a third bundle called "CoreBundle" (for example) where you place all the shared resource between your three bundles, namely the entities, some services (like twig extensions), config (with service.xml/yml), ... Also, you can delete the controller and views directories in this bundles, which are useless (don't forget to clean the app/config/routing.yml file by removing the CoreBundle controller injection) !

Then just call your entities in the right bundle with:

```
use MyName\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
```

Never create a model repertory not in a bundle, this is not the Symfony philosophy and you are really wrong !